# Android TextView displays strange text

Tags: android, textview

I have written an application where I need to show in a `TexView` text coming from the server.
I am experiencing a strange behavior when the text is set on the `TextView`.

For example, I am receiving
"español" from server but the Textview display "espacol" is there a way to fix the encoding or perhaps display "spannish" without mapping the texts in the application.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.format() with Locale what you want.

For example;

```
String text = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d", item.getText());
textView.setText(text);
```